# How can I create a decorator for a set of models with use the same table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, decorator, draper

I've got a Rails project which has a large set of models all using the same table through Single Table Inheritance. They are all different types of organisations.

Is it possible to use the [draper gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) to simplify my model without the need to create a decorator for every model which inherits from my organisation model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly decorate an object without the `#decorate` method.

app/decorators/organization_decorator.rb:

```
class OrganizationDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
end
```

app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @organization = OrganizationDecorator.decorate(Organization.find(params[:id]))
  end
end
```

You can also try with:

app/controllers/organizations_controller.rb:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController

  decorates_assigned :organization, with: OrganizationDecorator

  def show
    @organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```